# Help with sorting records in Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a score table that contains two columns: `user_id` and `score`

**user_id    score**
1               200
1               120
1               230
2               300
2               345
3               100
3               40
4               350
4               500
......

`Score.order('score DESC').limit(3)` lists the top 3 scores. Instead, how would I get the top 3 scores where each user only gets one spot on the list (their highest score).

The high scores from the above table would be:

user_id: 4 score: 500
user_id: 2 score: 345
user_id: 1 score: 230

Thanks!

Tim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to group your query:

```
Score.order('score DESC').group('user_id').limit(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Score.all(:order => 'score DESC', :limit => 3, :group => :user_id)
```

With new Arel:

```
Score.group(:user_id).order('score DESC').limit(3)
```

Comment: Doing it all old-school Rails 2 style!

Comment: yeah, I didn't have arel at hand before. I was about to edit it: Score.group(:user_id).order('score DESC').limit(3)

Comment: Question: Does it matter if group is called first or order is called first?

Comment: @zabba: not at all, any chain generates the exact same SQL. So just order it to best fit your reasoning of the query.